# MapKit gets [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I've been playing around with MapKit to display a map at the top of View in SwiftUI, when an address is contained; however, I keep getting [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior. when the user rotates the view.  Here's how I have my Map being rendered

```
HStack {
   if let region = region {
    MapView(region: region)
       .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3, height: geo.size.height * 0.2)
       .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
       .padding([.top, .leading], 15 )
    AddressView(recipient: recipient)
  }
  Spacer()
  .onAppear {
      let addressString = String("\(recipient.addressLine1 ?? "One Apple Park Way") \(recipient.city ?? "Cupertino") \(recipient.state ?? "CA") \(recipient.zip ?? "95014") \(recipient.country ?? "")")
      getLocation(from: addressString) { coordinates in
         if let coordinates = coordinates {
           self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
             center: coordinates,
             span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
           }
     }
  }
}
```

The recipient is in CoreData and is passed into the view.   Region is defined as follows: `@State var region: MKCoordinateRegion?`

Any suggestions on how to remove the error message?

here's the getLocation function

```
func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) -> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, _) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
                  let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(location)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with `Map` is that some of these logs are internal and unavoidable, but I fixed about half of them like this:

```
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion = .init(...)
    //  Fix for "Modifying state" logs
    var regionBinding: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
        .init(
            get: { region },
            set: { newValue in DispatchQueue.main.async { region = newValue } }
        )
    }
```

And then pass `regionBinding` instead of `$region`

Comment: I am not sure what .init(...) is doing, as I am getting `/Users/michaelrowe/Development/2023-CardTracker/cardtracker/SwiftUI/ViewEventsView.swift:43:51 Cannot convert value of type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'MKMapRect'
` when I tried to replace my existing @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion?

Comment: I just redacted my full initializer call since it’s not relevant and it’s long. Use your own region and modify the regionBinding to use an optional if that’s what you need.

Comment: Understand, so keeping my @State, and then replacing the region in my if let region = region with `if let region = bindingRegion` ends up giving me `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>' to expected argument type 'MKCoordinateRegion' ... I tried unwrapping the binding to get to the value, and that also didn't work.  Still receive the same behavior.

Comment: Your value is an optional, so you'll have to modify my code to use an optional binding: `Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>`. The binding itself should not be optional anymore, so you should get the value that the binding contains: `regionBinding.projectedValue`.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't have it working, but given that the value will never actual change, I am leaving the warnings for now.  I am only seeing them if I rotate the simulator, so may come back to this issue when I get further along in the overall project.

Comment: I am marking this as solved for now...